# DB2 Performance Tuning

Tags: db2

I have a DB2 Stored Procedure that runs for nearly 4 minutes and fetches 6000 pages of data.

Please may I know if there are any possible query-performance tuning methods in DB2 so that the procedure could be made to execute faster.

The basic structure of the stored procedure created is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_PROC(ID INT)
RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN

DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEMP1
(
    COLUMN_NAMES
)ON COMMIT DROP TABLE;

BEGIN
DECLARE V_PARAM_1 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE V_PARAM_2 VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE CURSOR1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR

    SELECT 
        COLUMN_NAMES
    FROM SESSION.TEMP1
    GROUP BY 
        COLUMN_NAMES
    WITH UR;

 SELECT 
    RTRIM(IFNULL(PARAM_1, '')) PARAM_1, 
    RTRIM(IFNULL(PARAM_2, '')) PARAM_2 
 INTO
    V_PARAM_1,
    V_PARAM_2
 FROM
    PARAM_TABLE 
 WHERE 
    PARAM_ID = ID;

    INSERT INTO SESSION.TEMP1(COLUMN_NAMES)
        SELECT COLUMNS FROM (....) WHERE(...);

OPEN CURSOR1;
END;
END P1@
```

The procedure consists of a select which returns values from the PARAM_TABLE to be passed as parameters to the original query. Multiple comma separated values are passed from the table to the query.

Thanks

Comment: Is PARAM_TABLE.PARAM_ID unique or primary key?

Comment: Actually PARAM_TABLE is View

Comment: did you use your visualizer?